# Overfull hbox in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, warnings

First of all, I've seen the answers which are recommending fiddling with `\pnumwidth` and `\tocmarg` -- changing these are only shifting the problem elsewhere within the toc, lof and lot.

How can I get no overfull hboxes in the toc, lof and lot (e.g. allow it to be sloppy and underfill)? I've also seen `tocloft` package but wish to avoid, as it causes problems with page headers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\today
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection containing extremely lengthy heading obnoxiously} % toc overrun by this title, words picked deliberately to exhibit the flaw
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the optional argument of the sectioning commands:

```
\subsection[shorter title]{longer title}
```

In this way LaTeX will show the longer title in the main document, using the shorter version for headings and toc entries.

Comment: Adding suitable ``\\`` or `\protect\linebreak` commands in the “shorter title” can be an option.

Comment: @egreg -- might not `\\ ` cause a problem in the running head?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Subsection titles don't usually go in the header

Comment: @egreg -- good point.  (stupid observation.)  thanks.