# Overfull \hbox in table of contents page numbers with kpfonts

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

It seems like the table of contents of standard classes (nor with `titlesec` loaded) do not adjust the spacing reserved for page numbers depending on the font used.

The example is the following:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{100}

\chapter{LoL}
\section{whatever}
\subsection{dunno lol}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: example]

The same does not happen with the default Computer Modern font. So the question is how do I adjust the width of the page numbers boxes to fit a three digits number, possibly in a way that works across different fonts?

I'm using `titlesec` to style everything in the real document so a `titlesec`/`titletoc` answer would be preferred. Never used `titletoc` specifically, though, so I do not know where to start from apart the docs which are quite terse.

Note this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257675/overfull-hbox-in-table-of-contents) since the overfull `\hbox` is in the page numbers, not the titles.

Comment: If you're using `titletoc` in your real document, it might be a good idea to also use it in your MWE here. Without `titletoc` you can change `\@pnumwidth` to something bigger than `1.55em` (the default), to not get overfull boxes. So your MWE is solved by using `\makeatletter\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em}\makeatother` in your preamble.

Comment: A perhaps better solution without `titletoc` could be `\usepackage{etoolbox}\makeatletter\patchcmd\@dottedtocline{\hfil}{\hss}{}{}\makeatother`.

Comment: I mentioned `titletoc` because I use `titlesec` to style section titles, but I don't use specifically `titletoc` because I didn't style the table of contents, yet. However, in the future I'll use it to customize the ToC as well, hence a `titletoc` solution will save me time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetpnumwidth{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{100}

\chapter{LoL}
\section{whatever}
\subsection{dunno lol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `titles` option (somewhat counterintuitively) instructs `tocloft` not to fiddle with the typesetting of the TOC title (i.e. "Contents") (same for list of figures and list of tables).